# Can I use Qlproxy with a different proxy than Squid?

Tags: proxy, squid

Is it possible to use Quintolabs QLproxy with a different proxy server than squid? Do I really need a proxy? Can it work alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

qlproxy is designed to work as ICAP server, Squid is one of those proxies that can act as ICAP client to pass intercepted HTTP traffic into qlproxy. It implies that other proxies which has ICAP client capabilities may also work with qlproxy. But considering "working alone" - as for now the only interface that qlproxy exports to its users is ICAP so *not* it can not work alone.